# FaceBook Facepile Parsed and Displayed but not connected to account

Tags: php, facebook, iframe, curl, xpath

My client is insistent that we display FaceBook Like-Box or FacePile content using our own layout and CSS.

To that end the code below successfully gets and parses the elements FaceBook is currently sending.  Of course this will break as soon as FB changes style names or IDs.

The issue is that when the code runs natively in an iframe loaded in a browser if the user allows it their FaceBook logged in status causes the FacePile to be dominated by their friends who "like" the page in question.

When loaded by cURL this does not occur.

What my client has asked is whether we can connect to the FaceBook account while still fetching using cURL.

I believe that is impossible and also the reason that FaceBook always implements these plugins as iframes- the cookies and sessions that belong to FaceBook have to be accessed by the domain that set them for security and privacy reasons.

Am I correct?  Is it impossible for my cURL script to tell FaceBook whose friends we want to see?

```
<?
$url="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like_box.php?app_id=&channel=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2FoDB-fAAStWy.js%3Fversion%3D41%23cb%3Df3ba86bb28%26domain%3Ddev.mysite.com%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fdev.mysite.com%252Ff1653c73c%26relation%3Dparent.parent&color_scheme=light&header=false&height=241&href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FmyFBPage&locale=en_US&sdk=joey&show_border=false&show_faces=true&stream=false&width=800";

$agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: www.facebook.com'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
$content = curl_exec($ch);

echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);


try { 
$DOM = new DOMDocument(); 
$DOM->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($DOM);
$elements= $xpath->query('//li');

$lis = '';

foreach($elements as $element){
    $newdoc = new DOMDocument();
    $cloned = $element->cloneNode(TRUE);
    $newdoc->appendChild($newdoc->importNode($cloned,TRUE));
    $lis .= $newdoc->saveHTML();
}

$elements= $xpath->query('//span[@id="u_0_1"]');

if($elements){
   $youlikethis = $elements->item(0)->nodeValue;
}

$elements= $xpath->query('//span[@id="u_0_4"]');

if($elements){
   $likecount = $elements->item(0)->nodeValue;
}

$elements= $xpath->query("//a[@class='_8o _8r lfloat _ohe']");

$newdoc = new DOMDocument();
$cloned = $elements->item(0)->cloneNode(TRUE);
$newdoc->appendChild($newdoc->importNode($cloned,TRUE));
$userpic = $newdoc->saveHTML();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is impossible to do using cURL. You will never be able to access the cookies.